# How to I use the LIKE operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-like

I'm doing a query using the LIKE operator, but it doesn't work.

When I run the query, there's no results, but it says "Query executed successfully".

Does anyone know why?
This is what I have done:

```
select Pr.nomPro, Pe.fechaPedido
from superVentas.dbo.Pedido Pe
inner join superVentas.dbo.PedidoDetalle PD on Pe.nroPed=PD.nroPed
inner join superVentas.dbo.Productos Pr on Pr.codPro=PD.codPro
where month(Pe.fechaPedido)=8 and Pr.nomPro like 'A%' and Pr.nomPro like 'T%'
order by Pr.nomPro
go
```

Comment: *"but it doesn't work"* What does "doesn't work" mean? Is `like 'T&'` a typographical error of `like 'T%'`?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do, and what is wrong with the results you are getting.

Comment: `Pr.nomPro like 'A%' and Pr.nomPro like 'T&'` should perhaps be `(Pr.nomPro like 'A%' OR Pr.nomPro like 'T%')`.

Comment: @Richard "Query executed successfully" means exactly that. It ran and ran correctly. You should add details like, "I have `X` records that should match `LIKE A%` and `Y` that should match `LIKE T%`. I expected `Z` records total, but got 0."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is a column value cannot start with 'A' and 'T' at the same time, you can use an OR operator if that is what you are looking for. Further, 'T&' is an incorrect way to search the wildcard.

```
select 
    Pr.nomPro
    , Pe.fechaPedido
from 
    superVentas.dbo.Pedido Pe
inner join 
    superVentas.dbo.PedidoDetalle PD on Pe.nroPed = PD.nroPed
inner join 
    superVentas.dbo.Productos Pr on Pr.codPro = PD.codPro
where 
    month(Pe.fechaPedido) = 8 
    and 
    (
        Pr.nomPro like 'A%' 
        or 
        Pr.nomPro like 'T%'
    )
order by Pr.nomPro
go
```

Comment: Remember that AND goes before OR.